# How to get a value from DB2 database and assign it to a Oracle database?

Tags: oracle11g, db2

I have a DB2 database And a Oracle database.
I want to write a java class that connect to my DB2 database and move all of its data to my Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use two datasources or two connections in your Java program.

Comment: I sold my software with oracle database to an organization with DB2 database I need a java class to move all data from DB2 to Oracle at the begining and also daily. Can you help me with the code, I am not familiar with java

Comment: That is a complete migration. You can contact me at angoca at gmail dot com

Comment: Tanx alot, I will send you an Email.

Comment: @navidsedigh - does the organization that bought your program want to move to an Oracle database?  Or would it just be easier to switch your program to use the existing DB2 datasource?

Comment: No they will still use their DB2 database but I want to use my own Oracle database because of that I need a code to make connection between them

Comment: @AngocA: can you help me with code about your answere: "You just need to use two datasources or two connections in your Java program." I just wanna select all data from DB2 and insert it in Oracle.